# Android gradle connectedCheck resume on failure

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Is it possible to resume on failure, while running `gradle connectedCheck`?

I want to use it in hudson, but it stopped execution after the first failure. How can I configure it to do the next test on failure? This way, I see all failing tests at the end and not only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer the question in the way you wanted but here goes anyway.  What I did to solve this problem was to use the Spoon testing framework as a wrapper around the Android test framework.  It gives you lots of advantages:

- You can use the regular tests you've already created
- Spoon produces permanent HTML output that you can save
- You can add screenshots to your test output
- The test output contains the log messages for failures

And, most relevant to your question, it continues on even when a test fails.

You can find spoon at: http://square.github.io/spoon/